# jquery doesn't submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

this is the button in jsp page:

```
<button id="saveProperty" name="saveProperty" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button"><spring:message code="be.ashblerje.personsave"/></button>
```

I don't know why jquery doesn't submit the form:

when the type of button is submit the form gets submits, but I dont want to be submitted in that way. when i make the submit as above and the type button it doesn't do anything.

```js
$('#saveProperty').click(function(event) {
  var url = getAppContextPath() + 'propertyExist';
  var nameproperty = $("#nameproperty").val();
  var address = $("#address").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
      nameproperty: nameproperty,
      address: address
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data) {
        alert("Property already exist!");
        event.preventDefault();
      } else {
        $("#formProperty").submit();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Add an error function to see if your Ajax succeeds. Look in the console

Comment: Is your jquery in doc.ready?  Do you run your script before the button has been created?  What if you use event delegation?  `$(document).on("click", "#saveProperty", function() { ...` Are there are errors in the browser console? What happens if you add `console.log($("#saveProperty").length)` right before your code?

Comment: Your `event.preventDefault();` isn't inside the event (it's in the callback after the event has finished) so does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send json data to server by ajax, you must add properties like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(send_data)
        }).always(function (response) {
            console.log(' response: ', response);
        });
```

Comment: Where does OP say they want to send json data?

Comment: he sent a js object as data!

Comment: Yes, a js object, not json.